# Thumnail Image for the post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I am developing a blog using twenty eleven wordpress theme.I want to display the thumbnail image of the post left side to the post content.I have used the set featured Image in the edit post section but not successfull yet to display the thumbnail Image.

Waiting for the help.
Thanks In adavce

Answer (score 1):

Open Twenty Eleven **content.php**

Find this code:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
```

Change it to:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>/*Will enable post thumbnails*/
<header class="entry-header">
```

You are done...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

- set a suitable thumbnail size:
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size
- add  to content.php, for instance before  or you can add it in the body before the content, whatever works for you
- adapt the style.css to allow the header and post meta data to wrap round the image, some ideas you can use

  .home .attachment-post-thumbnail { float: left; margin-right: 4%; margin-top: 15px; }
      .home h1.entry-title { clear: none; }
      .home .entry-meta { clear: none; }
      .home .entry-content { clear: both; }

Hope that helps!